# How to figure out if CSS transition is about to happen?

Tags: javascript, css

Here's my problem. Let's say I change div height from 10px to 50px and then want to do some calculations to its size.

Normally I'd just change the value and get, for example its true height (which can be affected with its/any of its parents padding, max-heights, the lot.).

However, when this change is animated with transition things get complicated. I can just wait for the `transitionEnd` event to fire and then check the element size but how can I figure out that transition is about to happen? So that instead of immediately checking the height I know I have to wait for the event?

Comment: can you zoom out a little bit more to give us a picture of what you are trying to accomplish? how is your code decoupled so that you have to "check" if a css transition is "about" to happen?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the size in the first place? If you have things that will change according to the div set them all at the same time and animate the whole lot...

Comment: Change the div size. Read the new size. Set the size back. Make your calculations using the read size while the div animates into position.

Comment: I have an element which will get it's properties changed and I need to do some calculations based on it's size. However, if there is a transition defined the element is at it's new size only after the transition ends. So, I either do the calculations immediately after the size has changed or, if there is transition, wait for the transitionEnd event.

Comment: There is no way to tell that an element is about to transition, however, if you can use CSS3 animations, there have support for: animationStart, animationEnd, and animationIteration. Transitions only have transitionEnd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for the computed style of the transition property.  If it matches the property you are changing, wait for the transitionEnd event.

```
if(window.getComputedStyle(element).transitionProperty.match(/\bheight\b/))
{
  //handle transitionEnd event
}
else
{
  //do calculations now
}
```

Of course you need to check for the browser's specific prefix.

**Edit:** I should also say that an element may have several transition properties set. Make sure you test accordingly (code is updated to reflect that).

Comment: Ah. Yes. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! For vendor prefixes (for example Chrome uses WebkitTransitionProperty) I just combined your solution with Modernizr's prefixed() -function and ta-daa! Works like a charm! Also, getComputedStyle polyfill for <IE9.